# Styling a funnel stack layout using native CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, positioning, pseudo-element

I want to show the data like funnel stack as illustrated below.

[image]

I was able to create the taper using borders, for example:

```
<div class="taper"></div>
```

and using the following CSS:

```css
.taper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    border-color: lightgray transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 25px 0 25px;
}
```

Of course, the idea would be to wrap this `div.taper` in a container, add other elements and position them as needed, a bit of work but doable.

However, I don't necessarily know how many lines (levels, 7 in this example) will be needed and I don't really want to do a lot of math to determine the width of each taper and so on.

If there a more bullet-proof way of doing this?

I don't want a JavaScript/jQuery based solution (trying to keep this lightweight) and would prefer to avoid background images (I may want to skin/customize the colors later and don't want to bother with image files).

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/fBax3/

Browser support: modern browsers are fine, legacy support, as long as it degrades nicely.

Comment: You'll have to either explicitly set each element width or use JS

Comment: Made it by setting widths explicitly, couldn't get the text working yet. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FEzug/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **TL;DR** : see the example at http://jsfiddle.net/97Yr6/

---

A way to create a funnel stack is with pseudoelements: with this basic markup

```
<ul>
    <li>1,234,567,890 <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>
    <li>234,567,890 <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>    
    <li>23,456,789</li>    
    <li>2,345,678 <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>    
    <li>234,567</li>  
    <li>23,567  <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>
    <li>4,567<span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>    
    <li>789</li>    
    <li>23 <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>
    <li>4 <span>Tooltip: 0</span></li>    
</ul>
```

we could create the funnel using borders, so we can draw a kind of trapezoid as a background in this way:

```
ul { 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 14px Arial; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: center; 
}


ul:before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -120px;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 800px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 120px solid #fff;
    border-right: 120px solid #fff;
}
```

The `<ul>` is 100% wide, so we could give it a `text-align: center` and all the amounts are properly centered

Then the space between elements could be obtained as well with pseudoelements again:

```
li:after,li:before {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   height: 0.4em;
   background: #fff;
   width: 100%;
}
li:before { border-top: 1px dotted #ccc }
li:first-child:before { border: 0; }
```

while the tooltip text could be positioned (the `<li>` needs to have `position: relative` defined), trying to properly adjust both `left` and `margin-left` properties (especially for lower screen resolution, but you may use mediaqueries for this purpose), e.g.

```
li span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

li:nth-child(2) span { left: 59%; }
li:nth-child(3) span { left: 58% }
li:nth-child(4) span { left: 57% }
li:nth-child(5) span { left: 56% }
li:nth-child(6) span { left: 55% }
li:nth-child(7) span { left: 54% }
li:nth-child(8) span { left: 53% }
li:nth-child(9) span { left: 52% }
li:nth-child(10) span { left: 51% }
```

basically this example may work even on `IE8` if you change each `:nth-child` with the adjacency selector (e.g. `li + li + li + ... + span` )

Hope it could be helpful.

Comment: I like the background trapezoid!

Comment: @Fabrizio Is there any way to align the numbers and text inside the stack elements. Since data inside the stack element aligned center and within that number is align right and text aligned left.

Comment: The Dabblet is broken ):

Comment: Hi guys, this is almost perfect for me. I just have one questions: is there any chance I can use this component inside a div with background color? When I do it, the funnel looses its colors (the ones defined in ul:before border colors). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ryan,

Thanks for your code example! I took your example and changed it a bit to reflect my project needs. Maybe someone will find this helpful.

```css
body {
  font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.center-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.funnel {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.one {
  margin: 40px 278px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.one .funnel-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -199px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 599px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #919eb1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.one .funnel-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 240px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #273445;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.one li {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.one li span {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.one li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}
.one li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
.one li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #919eb1;
}
.one li:nth-child(1):before,
.one li:nth-child(1):after {
  border-top-color: #919eb1;
}
.one li:nth-child(1):before {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
.one li:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: -200px;
}
.one li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #8491a5;
}
.one li:nth-child(2):before,
.one li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-top-color: #8491a5;
}
.one li:nth-child(2):before {
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: -170px;
}
.one li:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: -170px;
}
.one li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #778599;
}
.one li:nth-child(3):before,
.one li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-top-color: #778599;
}
.one li:nth-child(3):before {
  width: 140px;
  margin-left: -140px;
}
.one li:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: -140px;
}
.one li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #6d7b8f;
}
.one li:nth-child(4):before,
.one li:nth-child(4):after {
  border-top-color: #6d7b8f;
}
.one li:nth-child(4):before {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: -110px;
}
.one li:nth-child(4):after {
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: -110px;
}
.one li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #606f84;
}
.one li:nth-child(5):before,
.one li:nth-child(5):after {
  border-top-color: #606f84;
}
.one li:nth-child(5):before {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.one li:nth-child(5):after {
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: -80px;
}
.one li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #536075;
}
.one li:nth-child(6):before,
.one li:nth-child(6):after {
  border-top-color: #536075;
}
.one li:nth-child(6):before {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.one li:nth-child(6):after {
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
ul.two {
  margin: 40px 278px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.two .funnel-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -199px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 599px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #1b99e6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.two .funnel-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 240px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #003352;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.two li {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.two li span {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.two li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}
.two li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-top: 70px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
.two li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #1b99e6;
}
.two li:nth-child(1):before,
.two li:nth-child(1):after {
  border-top-color: #1b99e6;
}
.two li:nth-child(1):before {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
.two li:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: -200px;
}
.two li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #148ad3;
}
.two li:nth-child(2):before,
.two li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-top-color: #148ad3;
}
.two li:nth-child(2):before {
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: -170px;
}
.two li:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: -170px;
}
.two li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #117fc3;
}
.two li:nth-child(3):before,
.two li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-top-color: #117fc3;
}
.two li:nth-child(3):before {
  width: 140px;
  margin-left: -140px;
}
.two li:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: -140px;
}
.two li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0b75b6;
}
.two li:nth-child(4):before,
.two li:nth-child(4):after {
  border-top-color: #0b75b6;
}
.two li:nth-child(4):before {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: -110px;
}
.two li:nth-child(4):after {
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: -110px;
}
.two li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #006bac;
}
.two li:nth-child(5):before,
.two li:nth-child(5):after {
  border-top-color: #006bac;
}
.two li:nth-child(5):before {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.two li:nth-child(5):after {
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: -80px;
}
.two li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #005f98;
}
.two li:nth-child(6):before,
.two li:nth-child(6):after {
  border-top-color: #005f98;
}
.two li:nth-child(6):before {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.two li:nth-child(6):after {
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<br />

<div class="funnel leads estimated">
  <h2 class="center-text">Estimated 100 Day Lead Conversion</h2>
  <ul class="one">
    <li>
      <div class="funnel-top"></div>
      1574<span>Contacts</span>
    </li>
    <li>203<span>MQL2</span>
    </li>
    <li>112<span>MQL2</span>
    </li>
    <li>57<span>SAL</span>
    </li>
    <li>11<span>SQL</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="funnel-bottom"></div>
      4<span>Wins</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="funnel leads estimated">
  <h2 class="center-text">Actual 100 Day Lead Conversion</h2>
  <ul class="two">
    <li>
      <div class="funnel-top"></div>
      1574<span>Contacts</span>
    </li>
    <li>203<span>MQL2</span>
    </li>
    <li>112<span>MQL2</span>
    </li>
    <li>57<span>SAL</span>
    </li>
    <li>11<span>SQL</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="funnel-bottom"></div>
      4<span>Wins</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alteredstudio/2p5qf8LL/)

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a funnel with different colors for each layer in the stack:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/D9GLr/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1,234,567,890</li>
    <li>234,567,890</li>
    <li>23,456,789</li>
    <li>2,345,678</li>
    <li>234,567</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { 
    margin: 0 200px; padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

li:before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 30px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
}
li:after { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width:30px;
    border-top: 30px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

li:nth-child(1) { background:#ddd; }
li:nth-child(1):before,
li:nth-child(1):after { border-top-color:#ddd; }
li:nth-child(1):before { width:200px; margin-left: -200px; }
li:nth-child(1):after  { width:200px; margin-right:-200px; }

li:nth-child(2) { background:#bbb; }
li:nth-child(2):before,li:nth-child(2):after { border-top-color:#bbb; }
li:nth-child(2):before { width:170px; margin-left: -170px; }
li:nth-child(2):after  { width:170px; margin-right:-170px; }

li:nth-child(3) { background:#999; }
li:nth-child(3):before,
li:nth-child(3):after { border-top-color:#999; }
li:nth-child(3):before { width:140px; margin-left: -140px; }
li:nth-child(3):after  { width:140px; margin-right:-140px; }

li:nth-child(4) { background:#777; }
li:nth-child(4):before,
li:nth-child(4):after { border-top-color:#777; }
li:nth-child(4):before { width:110px; margin-left: -110px; }
li:nth-child(4):after  { width:110px; margin-right:-110px; }

li:nth-child(5) { background:#555; }
li:nth-child(5):before,
li:nth-child(5):after { border-top-color:#555; }
li:nth-child(5):before { width:80px; margin-left: -80px; }
li:nth-child(5):after  { width:80px; margin-right:-80px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach of dividing it into few divs.
[See the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/fBax3/8/)

I have to add code so an example:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="taper-left"></div>
    <div class="taper-center">123,456,789</div>
    <div class="taper-right"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.taper-right {
width: 25px;
height: 0px;
border-color: lightgray transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 50px 25px 0 0px;
float: left;
}

.taper-left {
width: 25px;
height: 0px;
border-color: lightgray transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 50px 0px 0px 25px;
float: left;
}

.taper-center {
width: 200px;
height: 34px;
border-color: lightgray transparent;
border-style: solid;
background-color: lightgray transparent;
background-color: lightgray;
float: left;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you could at least avoid to use empty elements for style-only purpose using pseudoelements instead. Markup would be cleaner :)

Comment: I like this approach because it will work out of the box in IE8 and nearly every browser.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on it, this version is a bit more responsive: https://jsfiddle.net/ehynds/j3fL6hof

```css
.funnel {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #409ca9;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:last-child {
  font-size: 36px
}

li:last-child {
  background-color: #a5c13f;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 90px solid #fff;
}

li:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 27px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0;
}

li:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 27px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
}

li:nth-child(1):before,
li:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 0;
}

li:nth-child(2):before,
li:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 25px;
}

li:nth-child(3):before,
li:nth-child(3):after {
  width: 50px;
}

li:nth-child(4):before,
li:nth-child(4):after {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="funnel">
  <li>
    <div>First Segment</div>
    <div>12,345</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Second Segment</div>
    <div>2,345</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Third Segment</div>
    <div>345</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Fourth Segment</div>
    <div>45</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```