# Background color on HTML/CSS funnel stack

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've created a conversion funnel to my dashboard based on the code presented on this article: [Styling a funnel stack layout using native CSS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439777/styling-a-funnel-stack-layout-using-native-css-and-html)

More specifically, using the code from this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/97Yr6/

And here is the result:

[image]
What I want to do, is to style the funnel widget just like the one in the left (white background and border). The problem is, when I put this whole "ul" object within a div with white background, it looses the funnel appearance.

It seems to me that the colors defined for the borders in .funnel > ul:before are not visible because of the z-index, but I really don't know how to solve it.

Here's my code (it's pretty much the same code in the fiddle):

HTML

```css
.funnel > ul {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .funnel > ul:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -220px;
      width: 0;
      border-top: 1200px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-left: 220px solid #F8F8F8;
      border-right: 220px solid #F8F8F8;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:after,
    .funnel > ul > li:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 2em;
      /*background: #fff;*/
      width: 100%;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:before {
      border-top: 1px dotted #ccc
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:first-child:before {
      border: 0;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li > .conversion {
      position: absolute;
      left: 60%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin-left: 100px;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:nth-child(1) span {
     left: 68%;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:nth-child(2) span {
      left: 64%;
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:nth-child(3) span {
      left: 61%
    }
    .funnel > ul > li:nth-child(4) span {
      left: 57%
    }
```

```html
<div class="widget-body funnel">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="single-number-lg">4,700</span>
      <br />
      <small>visitors</small>
      <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">10%&#x25B2;</span>
      <span class="conversion">
                  <span class="single-number-xs" style="line-height:20px;">5%</span>
      <small>conversion</small> 
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="single-number-lg">482</span>
      <br />
      <small>leads</small>
      <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">7%&#x25B2;</span>
      <span class="conversion">
                  <span class="single-number-xs" style="line-height:20px;">17%</span>
      <small>conversion</small> 
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="single-number-lg">235</span>
      <br />
      <small>trials</small>
      <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">6%&#x25B2;</span>
      <span class="conversion">
                  <span class="single-number-xs" style="line-height:20px;">9%</span>
      <small>conversion</small> 
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="single-number-lg">56</span>
      <br />
      <small>customers</small>
      <span class="badge alert-success" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Previous 30 days">2%&#x25B2;</span>
      <span class="conversion">
                  <span class="single-number-xs" style="line-height:20px;">4%</span>
      <small>conversion</small> 
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!--/funnel-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have (so far) managed this in order to alter the html without using z-index's etc:

```css
#container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#funnel {
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  border-left: 50px solid gray;
  border-right: 50px solid gray;
  border-top: 500px solid white;
}
.value {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -500px;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 100%;
}
.val {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  
  
  height:15%; /*change this depending on number of values, could be done in js*/
}
.side {
  float: right;
}
.val:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="funnel">
    <div class="value">
      <div class="val">
        123
        <div class="side">hi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="val">
        1234
        <div class="side">hi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="val">
        12345
        <div class="side">hi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="val">
        123456
        <div class="side">hi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="val">
        12345678
        <div class="side">hi</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @jbutler your suggestion is almost perfect, thanks! I just couldn't take off the last bottom line, and it's not responsive. But it's working already! Thanks.